# Why's the value returning null when the variable's being correctly changed according to the dd()?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I currently have 2 functions I'm working with.  Originally, the `fetchInventories()` function didn't require an argument because I'm fetching some query results I need to use which's happening inside the `getInventories()` function.  But down the line, I needed to make sure the query knows what's the current page number so I have to pass `$current_page` to the `fetchInventories()` function.

My question is: How would I be able to send the `$current_page` variable with the correct value?  When I `dd($current_page);` inside the `getInventories()` function, it correctly displays `2`.  But when I do the same thing inside the `fetchInventories()` function, it returns null.  I thought that `null` value got replaced with the aforementioned correct value?

What am I doing wrong & how can I rectify this?

Here's the `fetchInventories` function

```
private function fetchInventories($current_page) {
    $information = $this->getInventoryWithInformation();

    dd($current_page); // returning null here

    return $this->model
                ->join('item', 'inventoryitem.InventoryItemID', '=', 'item.type')
                ->groupBy('inventoryitem.InventoryItemID')
                ->select("inventoryitem.InventoryItemID", "inventoryitem.Description")
                ->select($information['inventory'])
                ->paginate(28, ['*'], 'page', $current_page);
}
```

Here's the `getInventories` function

```
public function getInventories() {
    $current_page = null;
    $inventories = $this->fetchInventories($current_page);
    $inventoriesArray = $inventories->toArray();
    $current_page = $inventoriesArray['current_page'];

 // dd($current_page); // correctly displays 2

    $this->fetchInventories($current_page);
                      
    return $inventoriesArray;
}
```

Comment: You're calling the function twice... In the first call, **you're passing `null`**...`$current_page = null;` then `$inventories = $this->fetchInventories($current_page);`, so of course `dd($current_page)` is going to be `null`.

Comment: @TimLewis rightttttt, makes sense!  is there an efficient way I can fix this so it won't return null the second time around?

Comment: It's returning `null` the _first_ time around, cause in the second call, you're doing `$current_page = $inventoriesArray['current_page'];` before passing it. The way you have your code now, since `$current_page` is the result of `fetchInventories()`, you're always going to have a call where `$current_page` is `null`. It's a chicken-before-egg scenario (granted not a 1:1 analogy)

Comment: Why you even need two methods calling each other? Don't write spaghetti code.

Comment: I don't think people write spaghetti code on purpose... We all have to learn somewhere. Martin does have a bit of a point though; you might need to clarify what this code does, and maybe include some reasoning to your approach. Additionally, you could always take your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and see if someone is willing to help with optimization :)